# for loop to export excel sheets not working

Tags: python, excel

Im trying with this loop, to export one table per sheet, and one workbook per value in "seccion",it succesfully writes the first workbook but nothing after that

```
tabs_preg = 
    alcaldia    pregunta    respuesta   estimacion  error   intervalo_inf   intervalo_sup   idp pregunta_label  respuesta_label idpr    seccion
    CDMX    p1_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p1_1    identifique la clase de vivienda particular casa independiente  p1_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p1_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p1_1    identifique la clase de vivienda particular departamento en edificio    p1_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p1_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p1_1    identifique la clase de vivienda particular vivienda en vecindad    p1_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p1_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p1_1    identifique la clase de vivienda particular casa independiente  p1_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p1_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p1_1    identifique la clase de vivienda particular departamento en edificio    p1_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p1_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p1_1    identifique la clase de vivienda particular vivienda en vecindad    p1_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Soy jefe(a) del hogar   p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Esposo(a)   p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Hijo(a) p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Padre o madre   p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Otro parentesco: t√≠o(a), sobrino(a), primo(a)  p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Sin parentesco  p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Soy jefe(a) del hogar   p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Esposo(a)   p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Hijo(a) p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Padre o madre   p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Otro parentesco: t√≠o(a), sobrino(a), primo(a)  p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p3_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p3_1    ¬øQu√© es usted del jefe(a) de hogar?   Sin parentesco  p3_1_1  vivienda y residentes
    CDMX    p4_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_1    ¬øAproximadamente cuanto tiempo tiene habitando en esta vivienda    Menos de seis meses p4_1_1  Percepcion sobre seguridad
    CDMX    p4_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_1    ¬øAproximadamente cuanto tiempo tiene habitando en esta vivienda    Entre seis meses y un a√±o  p4_1_1  Percepcion sobre seguridad
    CDMX    p4_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_1    ¬øAproximadamente cuanto tiempo tiene habitando en esta vivienda    M√°s de un a√±o p4_1_1  Percepcion sobre seguridad
    CDMX    p4_1    1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_1    ¬øAproximadamente cuanto tiempo tiene habitando en esta vivienda    No sabe/no responde p4_1_1  Percepcion sobre seguridad
    CDMX    p4_2_1  1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_2_1  En t√©rminos de delincuencia, ¬øconsidera que vivir en su Colonia/Localidad es..    seguro? p4_2_1_1    Percepcion sobre seguridad
    CDMX    p4_2_1  1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_2_1  En t√©rminos de delincuencia, ¬øconsidera que vivir en su Colonia/Localidad es..    inseguro?   p4_2_1_1    Percepcion sobre seguridad
    CDMX    p4_2_1  1   9999    9999    9999    9999    p4_2_1  En t√©rminos de delincuencia, ¬øconsidera que vivir en su Colonia/Localidad es..    No sabe/no responde p4_2_1_1    Percepcion sobre seguridad

for stage in tabs_preg.seccion:
    with ExcelWriter(stage + '_'+'estimacion.xlsx') as writer:
        for question in tabs_preg.pregunta:
            seccion = tabs_preg.loc[(tabs_preg['seccion'] == stage)]
            seccion[(seccion['pregunta'] == question)].pivot_table(columns = ['pregunta_label','respuesta_label'],index= 'alcaldia')[['estimacion']].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=question)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
"not working" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't made a simple error of not indenting your `tabs.to_excel` line?

Try this:

```
with ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for question in tabulados.pregunta:
        tabs = tabulados.loc[(tabulados['pregunta'] == question)].pivot_table(columns = 'respuesta', index= 'alcaldia')
        tabs.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=question)
```

Comment: Without full code and as mentioned in the other comment by Prune then not much more to go on to help you. Also consider using `pandas` and `openpyxl` when working with Excel files.